# Swift: Sign In with Google prompts on view load

Tags: swift, google-signin

While this isn't a critical crash, it bothers me that a prompt to load `google.com` from Safari the moment the view controller is loaded.

The following is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var signInButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var signInWithGoogleButton: GIDSignInButton!

    // MARK: - Overrides
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        signInButton.configureDesign()
        signInWithGoogleButton.style = .iconOnly

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
            } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (_, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error during Google authentication: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } else {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I had expected is that the prompt only appears after tapping the GIDSignInButton. However, the prompt appears when the view controller appears. Is there something that I'm doing incorrectly?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn() from didload and put it on button function. see an example of below:

```
 @objc func google_Pressed(){
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your signin() function call makes the prompt so wherever you’ll put it it will sign in. if you use sign in silently instead then it will not prompt every time the view is loaded and will sign in on the background